Debian & Broadcom: poor performance transferring files via network
I setup a new server running Debian Bullseye with Proxmox-kernel as a NAS to host mainly video content (so in general large files). I noticed an abysmally bad performance transferring files via SMB so I tried to do some test to find the bottleneck of the system.
My server:

Supermicro Mainboard H12SSL-i
AMD EPYC 7282 (2,80 GHz, 16-Core, 64 MB)
128MB RAM
ZFS root pool mirror 2x 240 GB ATP N600Sc Superior M.2 NVMe SSD
ZFS data pool striped mirror 8x 16 TB Western Digital Ultrastar DC HC550 Helium 3,5" SAS HDD
25 gigabit Broadcom P225P network adapter

My client:

Apple MacBook Pro M1 Max (64GB RAM)
Sonnet Solo10G network adapter

Both devices are connected via a UniFi Enterprise switch.
In all scenarios we're trying to transfer one large file of 30GBytes from the client to the server.

iPerf3 (iperf3 -c 192.168.109.244 -n 30720M): gave maximum network speed (9.39 Gbits/s, ~1173Mbytes/s)
rsync (rsync --sparse --stats -hr -e 'ssh' test/ user@server:/data/pool/somewhere/): resulted in a surprisingly bad transfer rate (~150 Mbytes/s)
scp (scp test/30g.test user@server:/data/pool/somewhere/): performed better than rsync but still worse than I would expect (~274Mbytes/s)
SMB is even worse but should work decently for the server to be of any use

Of course I suspected poor ZFS pool performance to be the culprit for the bad results but I was unable to confirm it:

fio --directory=/data/pool/somewhere --name=write --ioengine=libaio --iodepth=32 --rw=write --bs=1M --size=30G --numjobs=1 --direct=1 gives me a write speed of 900Mbytes/s
zpool iostat -v -y 1 1 shows that the pool is nicely balanced and write load evenly distributed over the 4 mirrors.

My major problem is the transfer speed of files over the network and I fail to find the bottleneck of the setup. Network seems to be fast and so is the pool.
Does anyone have any suggestions on how to test this further to find the bottleneck? I unfortunately don't have a Windows or Linux pc onsite with 10G network adapter to rule out macOS as the culprit. any ideas/suggestions are welcome.

None of those network transfer rates are all that surprising - the raw transfer rate of the network that you got from iperf ignores the latency of file copy protocols.  scp adds encryption, and it's not a very fast protocol to begin with.  And neither is rsync, and when you run rsync over ssh it'll be even slower.  SMB is, well, SMB, with lots of round-trips in the protocol.  Assuming you're running SAMBA, there are quite a few tuning guides.  And have you tried testing NFS performance?

Please post the output of zpool iostat -l 1 and iostat -x -k 1 when copying a large file via SMB.
